# OpenID Connect standard for searching for users

Tags: openid-connect

I have a single-page app which uses OpenID Connect to obtain ID tokens about its users. In those ID tokens there is information users consented to to provide to my app (e.g., e-mail address, name). Now, this is great but it works only for the currently logged in user. But I would need to search for data for some user who has previously provided an ID token (e.g., currently logged in user wants to send a message to some other user, so I want to get the e-mail address). Because I have a SPA I do not have a database of users, I use OpenID Connect for that. And I would like to avoid having to store user information into the database if that information is already present in OpenID Connect provider.

So I wonder if there is some existing standard which would describe how to query an OpenID Connect provider to obtain ID tokens for previously authenticated users (or their data in general, e.g., to obtain their name given an e-mail address, or their `sub` field given an e-mail address, things like that).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the data but not in an id token. The standard solution is to use the Rest API that comes with the OpenID Connect provider.

This is usually a SCIM 2.0 endpoint as in [this Curity article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/managing-users-with-scim/). Typically your SPA would need to call its own API which would then use Client Credentials flow to call the SCIM endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

> So I wonder if there is some existing standard which would describe how to query an OpenID Connect provider to obtain ID tokens for previously authenticated users

There is no such standard.